# How do you set a default value for a decimal column in an Ecto migration?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I tried doing the following:

```
add :balance, :decimal, default: 0.0
add :balance, :decimal, default: "0.0"
add :balance, :decimal, default: Decimal.new("0.0")
```

The first 2 don't work at all as newly-created records still return `nil` if I don't explicitly pass a value.

The 3rd one returns this error:

> ** (ArgumentError) unknown default `#Decimal<0.0>` for type `:decimal`. :default may be a string, number, boolean, list of
>   strings, list of integers, map (when type is Map), or a fragment(...)

The only workaround I can think of right now is to use [put_change/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#put_change/3):

```
def changeset(account, attrs) do
  account
  |> put_change(:balance, Decimal.new("0.0"))
end
```

However, I prefer to do this on the migration itself. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this same question on Elixir Slack and I was told that the first one should work.

I checked again and the first one DOES work. It's just that `Repo.insert()` returns the column as `nil`, but it shows up as `#Decimal<0E-10>` if I retrieve the record again, which means the default value does work.